# PHP Server Side error when submitting form

Tags: php, html, web, server-side

I have a trouble when try to submit my form to input it to my database, it still error when i submit the form. and the page show "The page is not available". Please help me to fix this..

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Guest Book</title>

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

i use database named "precious" in localhost
and the field of database is id(auto_increment), nama, kelamin, nomorhp, alamat, and keterangan.

```
<script>
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$link)
    die("Tidak Dapat mengoneksikan: " . mysql_error());
    else
        mysql_select_db("precious");
        if($_POST['Simpan'])
        {
          if(empty($_POST['nama']) || empty($_POST['kelamin']) || empty($_POST['nomorhp'])|| empty($_POST['alamat'])|| empty($_POST['keterangan']))
        {
            echo "
                (alert(\"Data tidak boleh kosong\"))";
        }
        else
        {
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_tamu(nama, kelamin, nomorhp, alamat, keterangan)
            VALUES
            ('".$_POST['nama']."','".$_POST['kelamin']."','".$_POST['nomorhp']."','".$_POST['alamat']."','".$_POST['keterangan']."')");
            if($query)
            echo"
                (alert(\"Data berhasil disimpan. \"))";
            }
        }
?>
</script>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["nama"]))
{  $nama=$_POST["nama"]; }
else { $nama=""; }

if(isset($_POST["kelamin"]))
{  $kelamin=$_POST["kelamin"]; }
else { $kelamin=""; }

if(isset($_POST["nomorhp"]))
{  $nomorhp=$_POST["nomorhp"]; }
else { $nomorhp=""; }

if(isset($_POST["alamat"]))
{  $alamat=$_POST["alamat"]; }
else { $alamat=""; }

if(isset($_POST["keterangan"]))
{  $keterangan=$_POST["keterangan"]; }
else { $keterangan=""; }

?>

</head>

<body>
<div id="header-wrapper">
<div id="header" class="container">
    <div id="logo">
    <h1> <a> Guest Book </a> </h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" accesskey="1" title="">Homepage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" accesskey="2" title="">Our Gallery</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="testimonial.php" accesskey="3" title="">Guest Book</a>     </li>
    <li><a href="#" accesskey="4" title="">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" accesskey="5" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="bannert" class="container">
   <span>WHO HAS BEEN COME?</span>
</div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="staff" class="container">
    <div class="title">
        <h2>GUESTS DATA ENTRY </h2>
        <span> Input the data below </span>
    </div>
```

The error maybe in the form, but i doubt at php_self. In the form..
i want these to be saved in the database named "precious"

```
    <div class="FormTamu">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">

       <label> Nama Lengkap </label>
        <input name="nama" type="text" id="nama "size="30" maxlength="30" />

        <label> Jenis Kelamin </label>
        <br/> <input  name="kelamin" type="radio" value="Laki-laki"/> Laki-laki
        <input name="kelamin" type="radio" value="Perempuan"/> Perempuan 
        <label> Nomor HP </label>
    <input name="nomorhp" type="text" id="nomorhp" size="30" maxlength="14" />

         <label> Alamat </label>
         <textarea name="alamat" id="alamat" cols="24" rows="4"></textarea>
         <label> Keterangan </label>
         <textarea name="keterangan" id="keterangan" cols="24" rows="2"></textarea>

         <input name="Simpan" type="Submit" id="Simpan" class="button" value="Submit" />
    </form>   


    <?php
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_tamu");
 $jumlah = mysql_num_rows($query); 
    ?>      

    </div>
    <p><a href="data_tamu.php"> Lihat data</a> (Total jumlah data ada 
<b><?php echo $jumlah ?></b> tamu) </p>
```

it is linking to other pages named "data_tamu". to see the list of guest of our website.
i think it's all correct but just show "the webpage is not found" when i submit, it's make me confused

```
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: sometimes it can, but sometimes not. not consistent

Comment: **You are wide open to SQL injection attacks I believe. You need to fix that, desperately.** Secondly, is the form generated, and submitted in to the same PHP file? If not, then $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] will not work.

Comment: i got it, thanks Phizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you maybe change:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
```

To:

```
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
```

Remove the action.

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting a form to the same file itself, you can skip the **action** attribute of the form. By default it is submitting to the current script file itself.

so try after changing the form tag like this

```
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
```